# Plane geometry question about tangential angles

Tags: geometry

[image]

I am very stuck. Please help, this is one of the toughest plane geo problems I have ever come across. A student on my free math hw help (on discord) asked and we are all stumped. I got A. not sure if I did it right. Thanks in advance! is $\triangle$ TAB equilateral
?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I thought that angle BAD is 70, and if triangle TAB is equilateral then it would be 60 +70?

Comment: okay.  why do you think $\triangle \text{TAB}$ is equilateral?

Comment: is it because of the tangents

Comment: $\triangle TAB$ is certainly isosceles.

Comment: but not necessarily equi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a triangle is inscribed in a circle, the arc opposite each angle is twice the angle.

So $\overset{{ \frown }}{AB}=130$ and thus $\angle TAB= \frac{130}{2} = 65.$

$\overset{\frown}{DA}=90$ $\Rightarrow$ $\angle DAB  =\frac{360^\circ-(130+90)^\circ}{2}  = 70^\circ$.

$$65^\circ+70^\circ=135^\circ.$$

Comment: nice thanks I had forgotten the rule between arc length and the angle

Comment: you are welcome!